# Is GMW different from Secret Sharing?

Tags: secret-sharing

Is GMW ([How to play ANY mental game](http://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/PUBLICATIONS/MYPAPERS/GMW87/GMW87.pdf)) protocol different from Secret Sharing??
If so, how is it different from Secret sharing?

Answer (score 4):

They are very different. GMW is a [multi-party computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_multi-party_computation) protocol while [secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing) is a technique to distribute a secret. GMW uses secret sharing as a building block but it also uses other primitives like an [oblivious transfer (OT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivious_transfer). GMW deals with the problem that multiple parties jointly compute a function (over their inputs) securely without revealing anything else except the final output value of the function. Note that a simple difference is that GMW does not have a particular secret distributor (well actually every party distributes secrets), as opposed to secret sharing.

Comment: @mallea I would say GMW is based on secret sharing but not solely on that. OT is also a very important component of GMW, which hides the intermediate values when computing the circuit/function.

Comment: @mallea, well if Alice and Bob are "distributing shares" to each other, then I'd say it is definitely based on secret sharing. Note that there are 2-party computation protocols (and even >2 party computation protocols) that do not use secret sharing.